# Property "function test()" of object [object global] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on button, i want function "test" to run, but it throws an error. Please Help?

```
$("#bttn").click(function(){
window["test"](params);
});

function test()
{
    alert("Test");
}
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'function test()
{
    var app = new sys.application(params);
    app.close();
}' of object [object global] is not a function
```

Comment: The code you posted does not match the error you’ve got.

Comment: @Boldewyn is correct, the code you posted implies that `function test()` in `window` is a string containing the code of a function. There _is_ a horrible way to solve this, but you should _really_ just make it a function.

Comment: Means test is not in the global scope.

Comment: @Boldewyn i posted the error, when i wrote my real code in function.var app = new sys.application(params);
    app.close(); // this has nothing to do with error, so for making question brief, i wrote "alert('test');" in function

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
// Adding a reference of the function to click event
$("#bttn").click(test);
```

Comment: Actually, its not "test" all the time, i can call other function which will be provided in text field later. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$("#bttn").click(function(event){
  test(event);
});

window.test = function () {
    alert("Test");
}
```

Comment: Its like, i have 3 function "function one(){}, function two(){},function three(){}" now when i write "one" in textfield later, and press button, it will execute "function one(){}". Thanks for response.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't help you that much, but if you describe your goal in the question, others can help you way better.